# How to validate a numeric field value in react using Yup? I want to check if the number provided is in increments of 0.01 or 0.1

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, formik, yup

I have the below code to validate the numeric value provide to be an increments of **'fraction'** i provide , which works fine for 0.25 , 0.5 etc but not 0.1 , 0.01

```
export function buildFractionStepTest(message: () => string,fraction: number): Yup.TestOptions{  return {
name: 'fractionStepNumericValue',
test: (value: number | null) =>
typeof value !== 'number' || value % fraction === 0,
message  };}

ValidationSchema = (): Yup.Schema<any> => {
return Yup.object().shape(
  {
fieldname : Yup.number().test(
buildFractionStepTest(() => {
  return `Value for field must be the nearest multiple of ${formattingSettings.step}`;
}, formattingSettings.step)  );}}
```

The below two cases are being validated properly

Example : Fraction = 0.5
Valid Numeric values :0.5 , 1 , 1.5 ,2 etc ( multiples of 0.5)
Invalid Values : 0.6 , 1.1, 1.3 etc

Fraction : 0.25
Valid Values : 0.25 , 0.5 , 0.75 , 1 etc (multiples of 0.25)
InValid Values : 0.3 ,0.8 , 1.3 ,1.6 etc

Problem arises for
Fractions : 0.1 / 0.01

Answer (score 1):

Okay I got this working .Posting it just incase someone faces a similar issue, may not be a perfect solution but this works for two decimal fraction and need to change multiplying with 100 to generate it dynamically based on the precision ( 100/1000/10000 etc)

```
export function buildFractionStepTest(message: () => string,  fraction: number): Yup.TestOptions {  return {
name: 'fractionStepNumericValue',
test: (value: number | null) =>
  typeof value !== 'number' ||
  value % fraction === 0 ||
  Number((value * 100).toFixed(0)) % Number((fraction * 100).toFixed(0)) ===
    0,
message  };}
```